# MPMediaPickerController for in house app videos

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmediapickercontroller

I have an app that has stored video files.  I would like to have the ability for the user to pick and play ANY video stored in my apps file, NOT a predetermined moviePlayer like,
//

```
NSString *movieFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle}
                       pathForResource:@"somemoviename" ofType:@m4v"];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                       [initWithContentURL:
                                       [NSURL fileURLWithPath: movieFile]];
```

//

so it would work just like getting a video from the photo library on my iPhone, but its doing it with the video files in the application itself.